# Why am i getting runtime error by online judge when the code runs perfectly on the local system?

Tags: python

QUESTION:

> Little girl Tanya is learning how to decrease a number by one, but she
> does it wrong with a number consisting of two or more digits. Tanya
> subtracts one from a number by the following algorithm:
>
> if the last digit of the number is non-zero, she decreases the number
> by one; if the last digit of the number is zero, she divides the
> number by 10 (i.e. removes the last digit). You are given an integer
> number n. Tanya will subtract one from it k times. Your task is to
> print the result after all k subtractions.
>
> It is guaranteed that the result will be positive integer number.
>
> Input The first line of the input contains two integer numbers n and k
> (2≤n≤109, 1≤k≤50) — the number from which Tanya will subtract and the
> number of subtractions correspondingly.
>
> Output Print one integer number — the result of the decreasing n by
> one k times.
>
> It is guaranteed that the result will be positive integer number.

CODE:

```
n=int(input())
k=int(input())
c=0

while c<k :
    if n%10==0:
        n=n/10
        c+=1
    else:
        n=n-1
        c+=1
print (int(n))
```

The code runs successfully on my IDE but the online judge gives the following error:

> verdict: RUNTIME_ERROR

Pls advise

Comment: Without knowing what the actual error is, it'd be very difficult to say. It might not even be a "real" error. It could be that your code is simply too inefficient, and is causing a "Time Limit Exceeded Error".

Comment: @Carcigenicate definitely not time limit otherwise it would have said so. Other accepted solutions have taken even more time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate pls give a hint if you have a more efficient solution. happy to learn

Comment: The problem statement says that there is one line of input, containing two numbers.  You're requesting two lines of input instead.

Comment: Debugging: I'd suggest looking at the value of n each time through the loop on a small test case, particularly after you divide it.

Comment: @jasonharper solution accepted thanks.